# When i try to run docker it says /bin/sh: [java,-jar,/bin/sh/hellotm-0.0.1-snapshort.jar]: not found

Tags: java, docker

This is the error I get:

```
docker run -dit openjdk:8-jdk-alpine

docker images

docker container ls

docker container exec  flamboyant_knuth  ls /tmp

docker container cp target/HelloTm-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar  flamboyant_knuth:/tmp

docker container exec flamboyant_knuth ls /tmp

docker container commit   flamboyant_knuth  syedwn14/hellotm-0.0.1-snapshort:manual1

docker images

docker run syedwn14/hellotm-0.0.1-snapshort:manual1

docker container commit --change="CMD ["java","-jar","/tmp/hellotm-0.0.1-snapshort.jar"]"  flamboyant_knuth  syedwn14/hellotm-0.0.1-snapshort:manual2

docker run   -p 8080:8080  syedwn14/hellotm-0.0.1-snapshort:manual2

Error:

/bin/sh: [java,-jar,/bin/sh/hellotm-0.0.1-snapshort.jar]: not found
```

Any help will be great.

Comment: Please rewrite this using a `Dockerfile`; you should be able to translate what you've shown above into `FROM`, `COPY`, and `CMD` lines, and then if the jar file ever changes or you need to upgrade the JVM it's a simple matter of re-running `docker build` to rebuild the image.

Comment: docker run -dit openjdk:8-jdk-alpine
docker container exec ecstatic_allen ls /tmp
docker container cp target/hello-world-rest-api.jar ecstatic_allen:/tmp
docker container exec ecstatic_allen ls /tmp
docker container commit ecstatic_allen in28min/hello-world-rest-api:manual1
docker run syedwn14/hello-world-rest-api:manual1
docker container ls
docker container commit --change='CMD ["java","-jar","/tmp/hello-world-rest-api.jar"]' ecstatic_allen syedwn14/hello-world-rest-api:manual2
docker run -p 8080:8080 syedwn14/hello-world-rest-api:manual2

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue, was working on Windows.

**Actual Problem**

Running the following command `docker container commit --change="CMD ["java","-jar","/tmp/hellotm-0.0.1-snapshort.jar"]"  flamboyant_knuth  syedwn14/hellotm-0.0.1-snapshort:manual2` from *cmd* or *powershell* adds *Windows line endings (\r\n called CRLF)*.

On running the following command, the docker container is started.

```
docker run -p 8080:8080 syedwn14/hellotm-0.0.1-snapshort:manual2
```

Once the docker container has started it tries to execute the bash command.

```
["java","-jar","/tmp/hellotm-0.0.1-snapshort.jar"]
```

But instead throws an error

```
/bin/sh: [java,-jar,/bin/sh/hellotm-0.0.1-snapshort.jar]: not found.
```

For the bash command to be executed properly we need to convert the line endings of this command to *Linux EOL (\n called "LF")*.

**Easiest Solution that I use:**

1. Install Git Bash (it provides a UNIX style command interface).
2. Run the following command from *Git Bash* `docker container commit --change="CMD ["java","-jar","/tmp/hellotm-0.0.1-snapshort.jar"]"  flamboyant_knuth syedwn14/hellotm-0.0.1-snapshort:manual2`.
   This will ensure that the line endings are *Linux EOL*.

**Note:**  On running `docker container exec  flamboyant_knuth  ls /tmp` from Git Bash you will face the following error message.

```
$ docker container exec elated_fermat ls /tmp
ls: C:/Users/<user_name>/AppData/Local/Temp: No such file or directory
```

Instead run the command on either *cmd* or *powershell*.

Here's [the Link](https://git-scm.com/download/win) to download Git Bash for Windows